# Finding green function using dirac delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying find the green function for the given the differential equation,

$$y'' + 4y' + 5y = 35e^{-4x}, y(0) = -3, y'(0)=1$$

This is the complementary solution I have found (using the IVs):

$$y_c(x) = -5 e^{-2x} sin(x)+-3 e^{-2x} cos(x)$$

I know that 
\begin{equation}
y_p=\int G(x,t)\ f(t)\ dt
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}G(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
    c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x),\ 0 \leq x < t
\\
    d_1y_1(x)+d_2y_2(x),\ 0 \leq t \leq x
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

So solving using initial values, G(0,t)=G'(0,t)=0, I have

\begin{equation}G(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
    0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,\ 0 \leq x < t
\\
    \frac {y_1(t)y_2(x)-y_2(t)y_1(x)} {y'_1(t)y_2(y)-y_1(t)y'_2(t)},\ 0 \leq t \leq x
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

which is:

\begin{equation}G(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
    0,\ 0 \leq x < t
\\
    \frac {(e^{-2t}sin(t))(e^{-2x}cos(x))-(e^{-2t}cos(t))(e^{-2x}sin(x))} {(e^{-2t})(cos(t)-2sin(t))(e^{-2t}cost)-(e^{-2t})(e^{-2t}sin(t)(sin(t)+2cos(t))},\ 0 \leq t \leq x
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

at this point, I try to substitute this G(x,t) back into \begin{equation}
y_p=\int G(x,t)\ f(t)\ dt
\end{equation}

but i end up with a completely unmanageable set of integrations.

My question is, am I doing something wrong in the above steps?

Comment: Why are you using the Dirac here? Your Wronskian is incorrect and the sign changes as a result of which function you call y1 and y2.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'' + 4y' + 5y = 35e^{-4x}, y(0) = -3, y'(0)=1$$

The homogeneous solution (using the IVs) is:

$$y_h(x) = -3 e^{-2x} \cos x -5 e^{-2x} \sin x$$

To find Green's function, we need the Wronskian of $(y_1(t), y_2(t))$ from the homogeneous solution, so we have:

$$\text{Wronskian} = W(t) = \text{Wronskian} (-3 e^{-2t} \cos t, -5 e^{-2t} \sin t) = 15 e^{-4 t}$$

To form Green's function, we have:

$$G(x, t) = \frac{y_1(t)y_2(x) - y_1(x)y_2(t)}{W(t)} = e^{2t} \cos t ~~ e^{-2x} \sin x - e^{2t} \sin t ~~ e^{-2x} \cos x$$

To find the particular solution, we set up and solve (note, from the DEQ $f(t) = 35 e^{-4t}$):

$$y_p = \int_{x_0}^x G(x, t)f(t)dt = \int_{0}^x (e^{2t} \cos t ~~ e^{-2x} \sin x - e^{2t} \sin t ~~ e^{-2x} \cos x)(35 e^{-4t})dt$$

The integration yields:

$$y_p(x) = e^{-4 x}(14 e^{2 x} \sin x-7 e^{2 x} \cos x + 7)$$

Of course, to form the final solution, we have:

$y(x) = y_h + y_p = (-3 e^{-2x} \cos x -5 e^{-2x} \sin x) + (e^{-4 x}(14 e^{2 x} \sin x-7 e^{2 x} \cos x + 7))$

After simplifying, we have:

$$y(x) = 7 e^{-4 x}-e^{-2 x} (10 \cos x -9 \sin x)$$

This process is identical for the Dirac approach you set up, but I am not sure why you are doing that and the answer is essentially the same.

Comment: You know your diff-e-q's! +1

Comment: Well, perhaps your various DE answers will help me "clear off the cobwebs" that have gathered over time! This site is good for refreshing and maintaining one's mastery/comprehension in many domains!

Comment: It seems slow tonight...I'm not doing terribly well either...I mean on math.SE...

Comment: I'm striking out tonight: $\sum$ (last four answers) $= 0\;$ :-(

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, and without going through the rest of your analysis, you should recognize the denominator of your Green's function as the Wronskian of the differential equation, which in this case is simply $e^{-4 t}$. (I think you actually have the negative of the Wronskian, you should check this.)  I imagine that should simplify your integral tremendously, assuming you are correct.